# get Json from url blackberry 10 native sdk

Tags: json, blackberry-10

I want to get a JSON object from a URL using the BlackBerry-10 native SDK.

Is there a tutorial or a sample that can show me how I can do this?

I checked twitter_sample. It is out date and doesn't work because The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview

Is there any other usefull tutorial or sample?

Comment: I am also looking into the same.